# Is it possible to override method of sealed class?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

In WinRT (C#, XAML), `ScrollViewer` is a sealed class, and I can't extend it, but I need to overwrite some methods (for example: `ScrollToHorizontalOffset`).

Is it possible to override methods of a sealed class?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No - in order to override a method, you *have* to derive from it, which you can't do when the class is sealed.

Basically, you need to revisit your design to avoid this requirement...

Answer (score 7):

You can't inherit from a sealed class, so no inheritance, no override.

See: [override C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx)

> The override modifier is required to extend or modify the abstract or
>   virtual implementation of an **inherited** method, property, indexer,
>   or event.

See: [sealed C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx)

> When applied to a class, the sealed modifier prevents other classes
>   from inheriting from it.

Answer (score 3):

As the  word `"sealed"` itself indicates that , it is protected from being **inherited or overridden**

*So, No inheritance implies no Overriding.*

please find [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) link to find more details about sealed class in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Sealed itself means that class can not be inherit and those class which can not be inherit means can not be access any property of that class in derived class.